# how to use kession attribute "beliefSystem"?

Tags: drools

I have a problem.how to use jtms value?

`

`

> Who can tell me the meaning of jtms?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try documentation for that kind of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the early days, Drools has implemented a basic 'truth maintenance' mechanism - the insertLogical working memory action (see the documentation).

The notion of a "belief system" is an experimental generalization of that mechanism. The rule engine keeps track of any working memory item that has been asserted as a consequence of the firing of one or more rules. In doing so, it holds some context about them, and uses this information to manage the insertion/retraction automatically.

The attribute 'beliefSystem' allows to configure the behavior with a (pluggable) strategy.
The default value is 'Simple', which provides the basic 'insertLogical' behavior for chain retractions

All other values are experimental:

- JTMS : extends the SimpleBeliefSystem, allowing for the logical insertion of 'negative' facts
- Defeasible : further extends the JTMS, supporting a conflict resolution strategy based on defeasible logic
- (others will be implemented)

I'll be glad to provide more details on any of these if needed